# Parsing full month and year in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible in SQL to parse a date in the format:

```
July, 1999
```

I have looked [at the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28SQL.80%29.aspx) for cast and convert, but have been uanble to find this specific format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/2332):

```
SELECT CAST('July,1999' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: remarkable! I would have spent over an hour scouring the web for the correct format,.